# change link color of <a> when hover over <tr>

Tags: jquery, html, css

When I hover over `<tr>`, the color of the `<a>` element should change to white.

I tried with jQuery something like that:

```js
<script>
    $('tr').hover(function(){
        $('a').css('color','white');
    });
</script>
```

But this changes the text color for all `<tr>`.
Any idea?

[image: html & css code:]

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? Can you not just use CSS for it?

Answer (score 10):

Add this line to your CSS file and forget the jQuery:

```
tr:hover a { color: white; }
```

If you desperately want your jQuery code to work, then you need to target just the anchors inside your hovered row:

```
$('tr').hover(function(){
   $('a', this).css('color','white');
 });
```

Comment: tr:hover a { color: white; } does its job..so simple. thanks!

Comment: Remember not to set a colour on your td elements, which will override the tr colour...like I just did. Doh!

Answer (score 3):

There are some ways to do. .hover method can have two functions (move mouse over, move mouse out) and you could implement both to change the color, for sample:

1 - by javascript (jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('tr').hover(
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.css('background-color', '#fff');
    },
    function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      // original color -> $this.css('background-color', $this.data('bgcolor'));
      $this.css('background-color', '#000');
    }
  );    
});
```

You can use `.data('bgcolor')` to get the color is setted by the style attritbute or the original css setted on the tag.

2) Or just add a css

```
.row {
   background-color: #000;
}

.row : hover {
   background-color: #fff;
}
```

and set it on the row

```
<tr class='row'>
...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if it would be relevant in Your case, i'm making website with one main color and second as white. Each refresh the color is randomized, so i needed hover elements to change color to this one. So i ended up with:

```
#menu-buttons>li{ color:#fff; }
#menu-buttons>li:hover { color: inherit; }
```

then i just assign randomized color to the parent element:

```
$('#menu-buttons').css('color',mainColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue; found this solution to be effective.

```
     div.cntrblk tr:hover td a {
       color:rgb(0,0,255);
     }
```